# Предположительный вариант - __getattr__ произвольного количества без вызова

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Мне нужно преобразовать вызванные атрибуты в список произвольного количества, при этом я **не хочу вызывать последний** из них:

```py
magic = MyClass()
var = magic.attr1.attr2()
```

Решение такой задачи мне знакомо:

```py
class MyClass:
def __init__(self, method = None):
    self._method = method

def __getattr__(self, method):
    if '_' in method:
        m = method.split('_')
        method = m[0] + ''.join(i.title() for I in m[1:])

    return MyClass(
        (self._method + '.' if self._method else '') + method
    )

def __call__(self):
    return self._method.split('.')
```

Смысл состоит именно в том, чтобы не вызывать этот последний аргумент. В итоге я хочу сделать так:

```py
magic = MyClass()
var = magic.attr1.attr2.attr3
print(var) # ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

Я не хочу сталкиваться с такой противной проблемой как *проблема x-y*, так что лишь предположу что я иду в ту сторону, я буду очень рад если вы предложите свое решение этой задачи или прокомментируете мои шаги

Как я могу решить эту задачу?

**Update**: так же хотелось бы увидеть более полное решиние с несколькими вариантами

Comment: три раза перечитал вопрос но так и не понял что, а главное зачем вы пытаетесь сделать. Можете описать более широко / абстрактнее - что вы хотите сделать / получить?

Comment: @MaxU Менять формулировку моего вопроса будет некрасиво, так что в этом и есть задача: вернуть атрибуты в списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, унаследоваться от `list`

```py
class MyList(list):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return MyList(self + [name])

magic = MyList()
var = magic.attr1.attr2.attr3
print(var) # ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

Конечно настоящим `list` он не будет, но формально условия выполнены, да и большинству функций не будет дела до того, настоящий он или нет.

Comment: А если я захочу вернуть что-то иное (в зависимости от этого списка? Подойдет ли это решение для этого? Например я захочу вернуть в итоге не список, а его длину?

Comment: Дайте конкретный пример (примеры). Желательно отдельным вопросом, к существующему мне добавить нечего.